# How to change php.ini in vagrant?

Tags: php, vagrant, yii2-advanced-app

I want to change for every machine on Vagrant (sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini change for current machine)

```
upload_max_filesize
post_max_size
max_execution_time
```

Please, help me. 
P.S. I tried

```
sudo bash -c \'echo export "max_execution_time = 60" >> /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini\'
      sudo bash -c \'echo export "post_max_size = 80M" >> /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini\'
      sudo bash -c \'echo export "upload_max_filesize = 80M" >> /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini\'
```

and

```
  sed -i.bak s/max_execution_time = 30/max_execution_time = 60/g 
  /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini

  sed -i.bak s/post_max_size = 8M/post_max_size = 80M/g 
  /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini

  sed -i.bak s/upload_max_filesize = 2M/upload_max_filesize = 80M/g 
  /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
```

But it doesn't work.
Thanks, for any helping

P.S.S. Answer (in Vagrantfile):

```
 config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
      sed -i.bak s/max_execution_time = 30/max_execution_time = 60/g /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
      systemctl restart php7.2-fpm.service
  SHELL
```

Comment: Did you run `service apache2 restart` afterwards?

Comment: I tried, but ==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
Failed to restart apache2.service: Unit apache2.service not found.

Answer (score 2):

did you run `systemctl restart php7.2-fpm.service`